# Flutter grid with different size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

how to create grid. My issue is that I want to display  widget in my grid view and each one of these widgets has its own content and can have different width, I am facing trouble with achieving that…

[image: Grid]
[image: Widget types]

GridView, Wrap, ListView, Rows + Columns, Stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget. Also check [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package.